# Using the == symbol in golang and using a loop to compare if string a equals string b,which performance is better?

Tags: string, go, comparison, equals, symbols

```
for i:=0;i<len(a);i++{
    if a[i] != b[i]{
        return false
    }
}
```

and just

```
a == b
```

I've found that the same string have different address

```
a := "abc"
b := "abc"
println(&a)
println(&b)
```

answer is :
0xc420045f68
0xc420045f58

so == not using address to compare.
In fact, I would like to know how == compares two strings.
I am searching for a long time on net. But failed...

Comment: == compares string contents as defined in the language spec. What is the question?

Comment: What did your benchmarks tell you?

Answer (score 7):

You should use the `==` operator to compare strings. It compares the content of the `string` values.

What you print is the address of `a` and `b` variables. Since they are 2 distinct non-zero size variables, their addresses cannot be the same by definition. The values they hold of course may or may not be the same. The `==` operator compares the values the variables hold, not the addresses of the variables.

Your solution with the loop might even result in a runtime panic, if the `b` string is shorter than `a`, as you index it with values that are valid for `a`.

The built-in `==` operator will likely always outperform any loop, as that is implemented in architecture specific assembly code. It is implemented in the `runtime` package, unexported function `memequal()`.

Also note that the built-in comparison might even omit checking the actual contents of the texts if their string header points to the same data (and have equal length). There is no reason not to use `==`.

The only reason where a custom equal function for `string` values would make sense is where the heuristics of your strings are known. E.g. if you know all the string values have the same prefix and they may only differ in their last character. In this case you could write a comparator function which only compares the last character of the strings to decide if they are equal (and only, optionally revert to actually compare the rest). This solution would of course not use a loop.

Comment: Another reason would be if constant-time comparison is desired.

Comment: @Peter Yes, that might be a rare case, but when that is the goal, often the algorithms work with raw `[]byte` instead of `string` values.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I asked this question because when I was studying the golang string matching algorithm Rabin-Karp, I wanted to figure out how the == symbol works to understand the algorithm performance better. It may not be appropriate for me to ask, but your answer has solved my doubts. Thank you very much.

Comment: I'd note that yet another case for a custom comparison routine would be using some [Unicode normalization](http://unicode.org/faq/normalization.html) on the strings to be compared. While Go goes a step further than, say, C in its treatment of textual data, still, the built-in comparison is oblivious to stuff like, say, a single character `ü` being "the same" as `u` and the combining diaeresis character `¨` immediately following it.

Answer (score 1):

Use the Go `==` operator for `string` equality. The Go `gc` and `gccgo` compilers are optimizing compilers. The Go `runtime` has been optimized.

---

This comment in the [`strings`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/) package documentation for the [`strings.Compare`](https://golang.org/pkg/strings/#Compare) function is also relevant to equality:

> Compare is included only for symmetry with package bytes. It is
>   usually clearer and always faster to use the built-in string
>   comparison operators ==, <, >, and so on.

---

In Go, the `runtime` representation of a `string` is a `struct`:

```
type StringHeader struct {
        Data uintptr    // byte array pointer
        Len  int        // byte array length
}
```

When you assign a Go `string` value to a variable,

```
s := "ABC"
```

the memory location allocated for the variable `s` is set to the value of a `StringHeader` `struct` describing the `string`. The address of the variable, `&s`, points to the `struct`, not to the underlying byte array.

A comparison for Go `string` equality compares the bytes of the underlying arrays, the values of `*StringHeader.Data[0:StringHeader.Len]`.

---

In Go, we use the Go `testing` package to benchmark performance. For example, comparing the Go `==` operator to two Go `string` equality functions:

Output:

```
$ go test equal_test.go -bench=. -benchmem
BenchmarkEqualOper-4     500000000    3.19 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkEqualFunc1-4    500000000    3.32 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
BenchmarkEqualFunc2-4    500000000    3.61 ns/op    0 B/op    0 allocs/op
$ go version
go version devel +bb222cde10 Mon Jun 11 14:47:06 2018 +0000 linux/amd64
$
```

`equal_test.go`:

```
package main

import (
    "reflect"
    "testing"
    "unsafe"
)

func EqualOper(a, b string) bool {
    return a == b
}

func EqualFunc1(a, b string) bool {
    if len(a) != len(b) {
        return false
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        if a[i] != b[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

func EqualFunc2(a, b string) bool {
    if len(a) != len(b) {
        return false
    }
    if len(a) == 0 {
        return true
    }
    // string intern equality
    if (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&a)).Data == (*reflect.StringHeader)(unsafe.Pointer(&b)).Data {
        return true
    }
    for i := 0; i < len(a); i++ {
        if a[i] != b[i] {
            return false
        }
    }
    return true
}

var y, z = "aby", "abz"

func BenchmarkEqualOper(B *testing.B) {
    a, b := y, z
    for i := 0; i < B.N; i++ {
        _ = EqualOper(a, b)
    }
}

func BenchmarkEqualFunc1(B *testing.B) {
    a, b := y, z
    for i := 0; i < B.N; i++ {
        _ = EqualFunc1(a, b)
    }
}

func BenchmarkEqualFunc2(B *testing.B) {
    a, b := y, z
    for i := 0; i < B.N; i++ {
        _ = EqualFunc2(a, b)
    }
}
```