# Sort indices of slice

Tags: sorting, go, slice

I want to sort the index of elements rather than sorting the slice. For `[]string{"dog","cat","apple","bat"}` I want to get `[]int{2,3,1,0}`

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "sort"
    "strings"
)

func main() {
    arr := []string{"dog","cat","apple","bat"}
    n := len(arr)
    indices := make([]int, n)
    for i:=0;i<n;i++{
        indices[i]=i
    }
    sort.Slice(indices, func(i,j int) bool {return strings.Compare(arr[i],arr[j])<0})
    fmt.Println(arr, indices) // [dog cat apple bat] [2 1 0 3]
    
    sort.Slice(arr, func(i,j int) bool {return strings.Compare(arr[i],arr[j])<0})
    fmt.Println(arr) //[apple bat cat dog] 
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The indices your `less()` function gets are indices of the sortable slice (`indices`), not another (`arr`) slice.

So use `i` and `j` to index `indices`. The result of course is an index to be used for the `arr` slice (that's your definition of the `indices` slice), so you get the comparable elements using the expressions `arr[indices[i]` and `arr[indices[j]]`.

And don't use [`strings.Compare()`](https://pkg.go.dev/strings#Compare), simply compare strings using the less `<` operator. For details, see [Go compare strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52830314/go-compare-strings/52831144#52831144).

```
sort.Slice(indices, func(i, j int) bool {
    return arr[indices[i]] < arr[indices[j]]
})
```

With this change you get your expected output (try it on the [Go Playground](https://go.dev/play/p/5X6OLtgJB97)):

```
[dog cat apple bat] [2 3 1 0]
[apple bat cat dog]
```